# Why is “seven” not pronounced as “seeven”?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

There is a so-called *magic e* in fourth place should force the e at 2 place to sound its name. But this rule does not apply to ‘seven’. Why?

Comment: Please quote the rule and any examples which follow this rule. I have never heard of the "magic" *e*, but I think I know what you're referring to. Bear also in mind that in English "spelling" and "pronunciation" *rules* are very loose.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: OP means the second **e** in, say, ***mete***, which indicates that the *first* **e** is pronounced long, as as in ***meet*** rather than short as in ***met***. I don't think the second **e** in ***meet*** counts as a "magic" one. Thus you might expect ***seven*** to be spelled ***sevven*** to be completely unambiguous. But as you say, to the extent there *are* rules in English spelling, they're *very* loose.

Comment: According to the "magic e" rule, the term [*mettle*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mettle) should be pronounced as *meetel*, it's not! It's pronounced **/ˈmedl/**

Comment: @Mari-LouA you've just borked the "magic e" rule. There mustn't be two adjacent consonants between the e's, so your example doesn't work :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've never heard of it being called "magic e", but I guessed as much.

Comment: It's more often called the [***silent e***](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/word-lists/english-words-end-with-silent-e.html) - which is not pronounced itself, but it often affects the sound of the preceding vowel (or sometimes *consonant*).

Comment: He did, I understood him :) They use this rule in Beka books for teaching preschoolers to read :)

Comment: *hat*---> hate, *mat*---> *mate*, *fat*---> *fate*, *mime*, *cave*, *stove*,  are you seeing a pattern?

Comment: You need to include your reference/research to show what that rule is specifically and how the rule applies to other English words. Otherwise, your question will be considered as "opinion-based" and closed.

Comment: This is another `Teacher's t Test`™ rules; these are approximations or assumptions passed down over academic generations from teacher to child who grows up to become a teacher, etc. They are all home-made, and they all leak -- sometimes badly -- because they're based on the fallacious presupposition  that  English spelling is sposta represent English pronunciation. In fact, it hasn't done so for at least 500 years. As witness the contrast of English spelling with [actual English phonemes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf).

Comment: @Mari-LouA We called it the *magic e* when we were teaching our children to read - seems like a century ago. As with all good rules there are exceptions. Another one is *heaven*, which is *heave* with an n added. Perhaps it should be spelled *hevven*. A similar rule with lots of exceptions is *I before e, except after c*.

Answer (score 7):

This "rule" has so many exceptions that it's really not a rule at all. Many probably are based on what language the word originated from, but that is so varied, it's almost impossible to try to learn which words came from where and how to pronounce them based on that.  So, it comes down to the standard answer for just about every "why" question when it comes to English:  "Because it's English"

Some exceptions:

- River
- Riven
- Sever
- Lever
- Seven
- Eleven
- Several
- Clever
- Never
- Ever
- Honey
- Money

Comment: Although, only one of the pronunciations of "lever" is an exception.

Answer (score 4):

The rule applies to words with the following pattern at the end of the word:

{zero or more letters}<vowel><consonant>e

and to words trivially derived from such words.  For example:

> "derive" ends with "ive", so it follows the pattern, and
>   "derived" = "derive" - "e" + "ed", and
>   "deriver" = "derive" - "e" + "er", so they obey the same rule

Notice that this rule usually involves a "silent e".

There is no word "seve".  "Seven" is not derived from "seve".  And the second "e" in seven is pronounced.  Thus, the rule does not apply to "seven".

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the rule that says if you have an **e**, then a consonant (optional), then another **e**, the second **e** makes the first one "say its name" (i.e. the first *e* must be tense.)

Examples: *Peter*, *meet*, *seek*. But this doesn't work with *seven* or *eleven*, for example.

**The reason the rule doesn't apply is because the word *seven* is a rule-breaker.** You could say it's an exception to the rule. Or the rule is not absolute. **It's a loose rule. This is English.**

Comment: @Mari-LouA See my updated answer.

Comment: I believe that _lever_ is a "rule-breaker" in American English (though not in British). But _ever_, _clever_, _sever_, _several_, and _leveret_ ('a young hare') are in all varieties as far as I know. So are _haversine_, _haversack_, and _hover_ (and, arguably, words like _cover_, though they have yet another vowel sound). The thing about rule-breakers is that they, y'know, break the rules.

Comment: And, as long as you agree to call them "exceptions" instead of "counterexamples", nobody ever notices when they're more common than the instances of the rule. And therefore nobody ever notices when the rule is wrong.