# Why is "rival" pronounced different to "pivot"?

Tags: pronunciation

In English language, open and closed syllable vowels are pronounced differently even when spelled similarly. This is probably the first rule every student learns about pronunciation.

Several examples of how open syllables are pronounced can be found here:
https://www.sightwordsgame.com/spelling/words/open-syllable/

More information about the closed syllable and other types can be found here:
https://www.sightwordsgame.com/spelling/what-is-syllable/

As per the subject, "rival" has an open syllable "ri" which is pronounced as per the open syllable rule. However, "pivot" which apparently has the open syllable "pi" is pronounced as if the syllable was closed.

The question is mainly whether this is an exception to the rule, and whether the only solution here is to just memorise how certain words are pronounced? Or is there something that the OP doesn't know about the open/closed syllable reading rules?

Comment: Maybe another informative example is to consider "rival" vs. "river."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “seven” not pronounced as “seeven”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71894/why-is-seven-not-pronounced-as-seeven)

Comment: "Because its English".  I've suggested a similar question that has further examples of of short syllables that are "open"   How about "si/mi/lar" (with short i both times)

Comment: @JamesK thanks this is helpful. So you have a rule and a lot of exceptions to it! It might be a too academic question, but I wonder how many exceptions percentage-wise exist in English and how does that compare to "more phonetical" languages, like Latin or Slavic ones? I have a strong feeling it must be a relatively big number.

Comment: @TypeIA or "river" and "driver"?